# how to change the background color of a J Checkbox inside the actual checkbox

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcheckbox

How to change the color of the actual box of a `JCheckBox`?

If I change the background color, it affects the color behind the text and checkbox, but not the color of the box itself.

If I change the foreground color, only the text's color is affected.

I can't find any other color properties.

I just want a simple `JCheckBox`, with one color, which is changes when I check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want a simple JCheckBox, with 1 color, which is changeable when I check it.

There is no property you can set.

You need to provide custom Icons for the check box:

```
checkBox.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...") );
checkBox.setSelectedIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```

Comment: and is there also an option for when the mouse enters the checkbox or should i just change the setIcon using a mouseListenener to do that?

Comment: Thank you ever so much, this helped me out. I just made some simple icons, and now it works. I Just used the mouselistener to change the icon on mouse enter or mouse exit

Comment: @LenardvanderMaas, glad it helped. `I Just used the mouselistener to change the icon on mouse enter or mouse exit` - you don't need a MouseListener. The API provides a `setRolloverEnabled(...)` method. There is a  method to set the rollover icon as well.

Comment: camickr, great, thanks for that! That makes a lot of code saving possible!